# Call to a member function getDateFormat() on null when running php artisan passport:install

Tags: mongodb, object, composer-php, laravel-5.3, passport-google-oauth

I'm getting this error message :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getDateFormat() on null in /usr/local/ampps/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 2992
```

when I'm trying to run this command :

```
php artisan passport:install
```

I'm using a fresh installed laravel v5.3.16 with mysql and mongodb database structure.

any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've Found the solution, I had to install laravel and then passport package then modify mongodb migrations to make it work.

It was order of this action which made this error.